# Autoreconf failed with exit status: 1

Tags: linux, github, autoreconf

I try to install `mp4fpsmod` on `Linux 4.19.104+ x86_64 Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS`. You can try this in Colab:

```
!git clone https://github.com/nu774/mp4fpsmod.git
!sudo apt-get install autoconf
%cd mp4fpsmod
!./bootstrap.sh
```

And see the error:

```
Running autoreconf...
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: adding subdirectory mp4v2 to autoreconf
autoreconf: Entering directory `mp4v2'
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force 
autoreconf: configure.ac: creating directory autoaux
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
configure.ac:83: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_DLL
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: 1. Please edit your question to include OS name and version https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61499480/edit .... 2. `configure.ac` has 18 lines, you have an error in line 83 ! .... Maybe get a new and better download. ... 3. Please try `$ bash bootstrap.sh`

Comment: @Knud Larsen  Thanks for your help. 1. Edited. 2. The repo was cloned today. 3. `bash bootstrap.sh` shows the same output as in the question.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.4 : Build the app in /home/[name]/tmp/ : `cd mp4fpsmod/ && ./bootstrap.sh && ./configure && make` : No errors. The app is one file, the executable `mp4fpsmod` ... which you can copy to any location.

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe you have installed something before. Please try to do the same in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb).

Comment: Why don't you build the app in /home/[name]/[folder] ... and afterwards make a copy of `mp4fpsmod` to the preferred location ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to build the app

Comment: See my above comments : cd /home/[name]/tmp/mp4fpsmod/ && ./bootstrap.sh && ./configure && make

Comment: When I run `cd /home/[name]/tmp/mp4fpsmod/ && ./bootstrap.sh` I see the error `autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1`. Run it in Colab and you will see the same.